# How Do I Find an App ID from an App Scoped Facebook ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My understanding is that a website using facebook API for oauth login generates facebook IDs scoped to the app.

If that is indeed correct, can one query the API for the app ID that generated the facebook ID? In otherwords is there an API endpoint that takes an app scoped facebook ID and returns the app ID that it's scoped to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible in general. There is no way you can do this for just any arbitrary apps.

App-scoped user ids were introduced to better protect people’s privacy. If you could now figure out that I am using a specific app (that you have no relation to), based on that you got your hands on my app-scoped user id somehow - that would undermine this measure.

There *is* a feature to map app-scoped user ids between different apps that are owned by the same business though, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business (but it doesn’t sound like that was your use case here.)